# Web Audio API create audiocontext from list item tag

Tags: html, web-audio-api

Can someone please try to help me wrap my head around this? How to I properly hook up a list item the audio context? It's probably really simple but I cannot find a way around it.

I have something like this:

```
window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext || window.mozAudioContext;

window.onload = function() {

    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
    var context= new AudioContext();
    var analyser = context.createAnalyser();
    var audioSrc = context.createMediaElementSource(audio);
```

HTML

```
<li id="audio" audioURL="https://...s3.amazonaws.com/media/Track_1.mp3" artist="A1"> Track 1</li>
```

It works only if I pass it like this:

```
<audio crossOrigin="anonymous" src="https://..s3.amazonaws.com/media/Track_1.mp3" id="audio" controls>
</audio>
```

I really need to do it by the < li > tag since I built an entire playlist around it. Please help. I keep getting this error message in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'createMediaElementSource' on 'AudioContext': parameter 1 is not of type 'HTMLMediaElement'.
```

Comment: The error is obvious, you should only pass media elements to `createMediaElementSource`, so you can't pass `li` to it.

Comment: Alright man, it's pretty obvious but how can I get around it? It has to be a way. Can I nest the <audio> in the <li> somehow?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no way to do this with the `li` tag. Why are you insist on using `li` in this case?

Comment: sad to hear that, all my work for the day was for nothing then...

Comment: You could wrap the audio tag inside the <li>, like <ul><li><audio></audio></li> and have multiple <li>?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with those `li`s where `audio` tag can't do it for you?

Comment: An audio player with a playlist that outputs a bar visualizer. The li's handle the audio controls and playlist. Something like this: https://codepen.io/pramodkumarboda/pen/pEjzKk

Comment: @ aquilesb tried it and it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you are passing the li html element as source when it has to be a  element. Without a code example it is hard to help. I believe you can achieve your goal using the code below.

```js
const audioEl = document.getElementById("audio")

function play (event){
  const audioURL = event.target.attributes.audioUrl.value;
  audioEl.src = audioURL
  audioEl.play();
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li onClick="play(event)" audioUrl="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/horse.ogg">Hourse</li>
  <li  onClick="play(event)" audioUrl="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/examples/t-rex-roar.mp3">Rex 1</li>
</ul>
<audio id="audio" controls></audio>
```

Comment: Thank you @aquilesb. It works now, the audiocontext is created but I cannot see the visualization on the canvas. No errors in the console.

Comment: If you want to see the player, you have to create the audio tag and programmatically change the audio url instead of keep creating a `new Audio` variable every time

Comment: Would you be so kind to edit your answer and provide an example? I am curious to learn how it's properly done.

Comment: Done, https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2012/02/HTML5-audio-and-the-Web-Audio-API-are-BFFs